# Automatically changing package version when the desired version cannot be found

Tags: python, docker, installation, pip, requirements.txt

I'm building a Docker image with a requirements.txt file. Every time I build the image it keeps failing due to some package version not being present. For example

```
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=tensorflow/tensorflow
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER


# 2) change to root to install packages
USER root

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt


# 3) install packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement msrestazure==0.5.4 
(from -r requirements.txt (line 66)) (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2,
 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.4.0rc1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 
0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.4.10, 0.4.11, 0.4.12, 0.4.13, 0.4.14, 0.4.15, 0.4.16, 0.4.17, 0.4.18, 
0.4.19, 0.4.20, 0.4.21, 0.4.22, 0.4.23, 0.4.24, 0.4.25, 0.4.26, 0.4.27, 0.4.28, 0.4.29, 
0.4.30, 0.4.31, 0.4.32, 0.4.33, 0.4.34, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4)
#6 9.178 ERROR: No matching distribution found for msrestazure==0.5.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 66))
```

To get around this I've just been changing the version of the package in my requirements.txt to the most up to date version that docker can find. I was wondering if there was a way to do this programmatically. Like is there some flag or option I can use to automatically install the latest version of the package that docker can find if the version I have in my requirements.txt file does not exist/cannot be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not specifying any version at all in a `requirements.txt` will result in the most recent version being used, provided it does not conflict.

In your case I would suggest running `docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow` to get an interactive shell in the environment, then installing all your packages without a version specified. Test that that works, and if it does, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate a new requirements file that works in that environment, so that your requirements can be stable.

You'll also have to pin the `tensorflow/tensorflow` image, as if you use `latest` as you're doing now then you can't be sure your requirements will be available in the future.

Make sure to [copy the `requirements.txt` file out](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) before exiting the container.

Comment: Oh you're entirely right I completely forgot about just leaving the version out